# How to programmatically create a Quick Campaign in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: visual-studio, dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to create a "quick campaign" in code, but I don't find a class to do that.

I found the way to create a list and add users to that list. But I can't continue, because I don't know the way.

Comment: What's a campaing? I would think its a typo and should be campaign. But then again, I don't know what you would mean with campaign in this context either.

Comment: Google translates the second half as "Hi I'm trying to create a campaign on it, but not to do encuetro class (or so). He managed to create a marketing list and add users. But I do not know how to continue. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!"

Comment: Does that suggest he needs a basic database design and interface?

Comment: Maybe looking for a way to send emails to a marketing list?

Comment: The questions is tagged as CRM - a "Quick Campaign" is a type of object in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Comment: Ah good catch, have reworded the title to make more sense

Answer (score 2):

this is an old post but I thought I'd reply anyway.

The 'quick campaign' entity in CRM is called 'bulkoperation'.  The Quick Campaign Wizard only creates activity records of other types, such as phone calls or tasks.  The bulk operation is that which actually performs the action of distributing the campaign.  A quick campaign is not a standard CRM entity.

As far as I know, you can't create a bulkoperation record using code - there is no 'Create' method for this class.  I assume this is because the bulk operations are tied to the CRM platform too tightly.

The closest way to simulate creating a quick campaign, I would suggest, is to perform the actions of the Quick Campaign Wizard using code and create the associated activities that the Wizard would normally create.  That, or use the Campaign entity, which can be managed with code.

Search the CRM SDK for the bulkoperation class for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Quick Campaign you can use the PropagateByExpressionRequest.  Microsofot has provide sample code on how to do this -> 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328526.aspx